# Unable to sort values based on a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that have 1200 rows and 7 columns. I have a column named 'score' based on which I wish to sort the entire dataframe. I came across the sort_values function, but I am unable to sort them correct. Below is a snip of the 'Before' and 'After' of the dataframe, that shows some values being sorted properly and conflicting values appearing in between. I have attached images of how my column looks before and after sorting.

[Before sorting the column in the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvZho.png)

[After sorting the column in the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIJ6V.png)

My code:

> my_df.sort_values("score", ascending=True, inplace = True)

Here, 'my_df' is the name of the dataframe.
Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `score` looks like str, try `my_df['score'] = pd.to_numeric(my_df['score'])` first maybe..? Use `errors='coerce'` argument if there are non-numeric characters in that column. See docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: Glad it helped :) happy coding

Comment: @ChrisA Not sure how I can mark your answer as accepted. I am only getting a 'flag' symbol

Comment: No need buddy, it's just a comment rather than an answer